# Getting 404 Not Found while PHP works in background - Nginx

Tags: nginx, php, php5

I have noticed that I get 404 - Not Found when calling a .php file even if the script works in background. The php file downloads a long Json and populates a db until I close the window.

I am using **Php 5** and **Nginx 1.9.3.**

How can I fix this problem, is it a configuration problem?
Thank you for your time.

**EDIT**

This problem occurs only with long JSONs. I am testing it on localhost and I will format this installation after the test.

- example url: http://localhost/php/get_visit_log.php
- configuration: Here are a few screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your site configuration and/or example URLs. Remember to obfuscate any confidential/personal information.

Comment: I understand the downvote. @Weboide Which information do you need exactly? Please see my edit.